# Python - Converting string values of list into float values

Tags: python, string, floating-point

I want to store the float values of list. The values are extracted from csv file.

The code I have written:

```
import numpy as np

import csv
from sklearn import datasets, metrics
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from neupy import algorithms, environment

environment.reproducible()

data1 = open('data.csv','r').read().split("\n")

target1 = open('target.csv','r').read().split("\n")

x1 = [[float(n) for n in e] for e in data1 ]
y1 = [[float(s) for s in f] for f in target1 ]
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x1,y1,train_size=0.7)

pnn = algorithms.PNN(std=10,verbose=False)

pnn.train(x_train, y_train)
y_predicted = pnn.predict(x_test)
print(metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_predicted))
```

The error I am encountered with is:

```
WARNING (theano.configdefaults): g++ not detected ! Theano will be 
unable to execute optimized C-implementations (for both CPU and GPU) 
and will default to Python implementations. Performance will be 
severely degraded. To remove this warning, set Theano flags cxx to
an empty string.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\pnn-3.py", line 16, in <module>
    x1 = [[float(n) for n in e] for e in data1 ]
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\pnn-3.py", line 16, in <listcomp>
    x1 = [[float(n) for n in e] for e in data1 ]
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\pnn-3.py", line 16, in <listcomp>
    x1 = [[float(n) for n in e] for e in data1 ]
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '.'
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then come back and rephrase your question

Comment: I would say that `e` is already a string representing a float, so the conversion (kind of) works until it chokes on the dot. Try `x1 = [float(n) for n in data1]`

Comment: Same Error again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you do this:

```
data1 = open('data.csv','r').read().split("\n")
```

`data1` is a list of *strings*

So then you do this:

```
x1 = [[float(n) for n in e] for e in data1 ]
```

you're iterating on strings, and then on the *characters* of the string. So conversion (kind of) works for the first digits of the first float, then chokes on `.` (ex: `"3.1416"`: `3` is converted to a float (works, in a funny way), but then you encounter `.` and it fortunately fails).

You just forgot to split your line according to the csv separator.

I would use the `csv` module to split the lines into rows for me and do:

```
with open('data.csv','r') as f:
   cr = csv.reader(f,delimiter=";")  # change to whatever your delimiter is
   x1 = [[float(n) for n in row] for row in cr]
```